# Console bug when consoling html elements. Visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

when I am trying to console.log(h1.parentNode). I am getting 2 different outputs into the console, and it seems completely random as to which output I get.
For reference, h1 is just a variable with document.querySelector('h1') saved to it.

See two images below.

[first potential output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzB8S.png)
[second potential output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JZPZ.png)

It's very odd. When I load the page, one of these two outputs is put into the console, and it seems completely random. I can refresh the page 10 times, and sometimes I get the first option 9 times and the second option once, or vice-versa.

I would like it if only the second option appeared, where it consoles the entire element in question... Not sure why VScode is doing this, or why it's happening.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because some of the time, it's console logging the element before the DOM content is fully loaded. You can confirm this by running the following:

```
addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
  console.log(h1.parentNode);
});
let _h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
console.log(_h1.parentNode);
```

[image: console logging both outcomes]

Comment: Ohhh I see! Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: You could wrap anything that consoles out a DOM element in that DOMContentLoaded event listener